# Numpy argsort - what is happening?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array called **arr1** defined like following.

```
arr1 = np.array([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9])
print(arr1.argsort())

array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  9,  8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
        17], dtype=int64)
```

I expected all the indices of the array to be in **numeric order** but indices 8 and 9 seems to have flipped.

Can someone help on why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.argsort` by default uses the quicksort algorithm which is not stable. You can specify `kind = "stable"` to perform a stable sort, which will preserve the order of equal elements:

```
import numpy as np 

arr1 = np.array([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9])
print(arr1.argsort(kind="stable"))
```

It gives:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to fix it. Also learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

Because it will sort according to the quick sort algorithm if you follow the steps you will see that is why they are flipped. `https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html`